# Makefile rebuilds everything every time, why?

Tags: makefile

I have simple makefile here:

```
SOURCES= $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
NAMES= $(patsubst %.c, %, $(SOURCES))
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -o     
TASKS_IN_DIRS= $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJECTS)) $(addprefix bin/,$(NAMES))

all: $(NAMES)

$(NAMES): %: %.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o bin/$@ obj/$^
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) obj/$@ $<
clean:
    rm -rf $(TASKS_IN_DIRS)
```

1. Getting all the c files names.
2. Making from them simple names(without extension) and object names.
3. Doing things

And what matters - all works, but works every time i print make(compiling and linking all the files). even if i don't changed anything and i do it few times in row, is something wrong with dependencies?

I expected something like "blabla is up to date" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) obj/$@ $<
```

is looking in your current directory for your .o files. Since they're not there it's rebuilding them.

The following does what you want.

```
SOURCES= $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS:= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS:= $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJECTS))
NAMES:= $(patsubst %.c, %, $(SOURCES))
NAMES:= $(addprefix bin/,$(NAMES))
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -o
TASKS_IN_DIRS=$(OBJECTS) $(NAMES)

all: $(NAMES)

$(NAMES): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TASKS_IN_DIRS)
```

Comment: in case this "$(CC) -o $@ $^" there is error because it tries something like gcc -o name task1.o task2.o task3.o, and every of tasks have own main. but when changed to "$(CC) -o $@ $<" it all works like a clock, i'm very thankful. When i will have enough reputation to vote, your answer will have +1 from me. Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops missed that. Updated the answer, I was just running it with a test of 1.c file.

Answer (score 5):

*You lied to make.* You promised that each of the`$(NAMES)` targets creates its object file in the current directory, but due to `$(CC) -o bin/$@ obj/$^` it is created in the `bin` directory.

At the next `make` invocation, it can't find the object files and runs each command again.

*Hard and Fast Rule for Makefiles:* each non-PHONY target must use a plain `$@` somewhere in its commands to indicate the file it creates.