# Makefile builds everything each time

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile (reduced to ignore irrelevant stuff):

```
BUILD_DIR=./build
OBJS = \
  $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o \
  $(BUILD_DIR)/common.o \
  ...

roo: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

.PHONY: $(BUILD_DIR)
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/passes

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

However, every object file is recompiled every time, even thought I'm following the rule to directly use `$@` in each non-phony target.

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598747/makefile-rebuilds-everything-every-time-why) because I'm applying the subdirectory in the rule rather than in the recipe, but I may be wrong? How do I get Make to correctly track the dependencies in the build directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stated that `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o` depends on `$(BUILD_DIR)`, but that directory will be touched every time a file is added to that directory (for example by this rule itself).  That is, `$(BUILD_DIR)` will *always* be newer than its target.

It looks like you want to create the build directory automatically.  The best way to do that, I think, is

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/passes
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks; fixed it perfectly

Comment: Or you can create `create-dir:` PHONY-target. In this target you can run `mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}/passes` and the `${BUILD_DIR}/%.o`'s dependency will `create-dir` - so you can re-use it if needed.

Comment: There's no point in doing the test.  You might as well just run `mdir -p`.  It will be a no-op if the directory already exists.

Comment: @MadScientist d'you know, that's never occurred to me before, in years of experience with Make! But you're perfectly correct. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.